# Plugin content type URLs break after Wordpress plugin upgrades

Tags: wordpress

We use a plugin that creates a content type and dynamically generates pages for that type. It works fine except that when when we upgrade plugins (especially The Event Calendar, which also creates a content type, but doesn't experience this problem), this sometimes (but not reliably) causes all of the page URLs generated by the plugin to stop existing. When you go to those URLs, you get a 404 error.

This problem can be fixed by going to the site's permalinks page and (without making any changes) saving the settings.

I looked for a solution that would prevent the problem from happening, but have not been able to find one. I wasn't able to figure out a way to mimic what happens when you save the permalinks settings for each site, and I haven't been able to figure out what might be triggering the problem. I currently "solve" the problem by using a Selenium script to go through each permalinks page in our multisite and click the save button on each automatically after I update plugins.

How can I:

1. Track down the source of the problem.
2. Set up a content type that will not unset itself in the wrong circumstances.
3. Failing either of those things, implement a backend solution that will do what I am currently doing on the frontend, but in a fully automatic way.